# (X,Y,Z) coordinate movement

Tags: 3d

I have created a sphere, inside the sphere (cell) is another smaller sphere (nuclei) located at one end and at the other end of the sphere is a structure call microtubules.

The microtubules had a center point and then there are line that extend from the point to the edge of nuclei and also to the edge of the cell.

I have points (viruses) that move throughout the cell. Once the virus is on the microtubules structure ( assuming it attaches to the structure from the cell edge), it must move towards the center of the microtubules and eventually move down the line towards the nuclei.

I have already figured out how to determine if the virus is on the microtubules structure however I cant figure out how to move it down the line. I figured it out in 2D space using the quadrant system, but I cant wrap my head doing it in 3D space.

My question is: Once the virus is on the microtubules how do I update the coordinates to move it towards the center and then towards the nuclei?

Thank You

Comment: Is the path a straight line or an arc?

Comment: Could you just rephrase your question avoiding specific stuff like microtubules, etc?

Comment: Once the point is on the 3D line how do I update the coordinates to move it towards the center point and then towards the end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

So your questions boils down to "How do I move an object from one point to another (over multiple frames) in 3D?"

The answer depends completely upon how you have implemented object movement.  But the basic concept is:

1. Subtract the "from" point's location from the "to" point's location.  The result is a vector that points in the direction you want the object to move.
2. Change the magnitude of this vector (without changing its direction) so that this vector can be your object's Velocity vector.
3. Now that you have the object's starting location and velocity, animate it moving over time until you reach the destination point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to smoothly interpolate an object O between two points A and B. You can use linear interpolation, cubic spline interpolation, etc.

**Linear interpolation**
Let's say that:

- O is at location A at frame Fa;
- O is at location B at frame Fb;

Then for Fc between Fa and Fb, you can compute C as:

C = A + (B-A)(Fc - Fa)/(Fb - Fa)

Basically, you consider starting point A, to which you add the translation performed until now. The translation performed until now is the total translation to perform (B - A) weighted by the normalized number of frames (so between 0 and 1) since interpolation started so (Fc - Fa)/(Fb - Fa)

If Fc = Fa (so we did not started interpolation yet), then C = A;
If Fc = Fb (so we should reach final position), then C = B;

This interpolation will result in a linear trajectory. However, O speed is constant. That means that O will start, travel and end at the exact same speed. In animation, this rarely gives good results. Other techniques use cubic interpolation, Kochanek–Bartels spline, etc. Those interpolation techniques are much more complex to implement but will give you a finer control about how fast your point travels along the line.